# Traefik route specific route to different service

Tags: traefik

I have an api in python fastapi and want to replace a high load and very important http route to a newly created service in golang. So I want to send `local.com/api/update` to the golang services instead of the fastapi services but keep sending all the other request to the fastapi service.

How can I configure this with traefik k8s?

Here is my k3s config:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: staging-api
  namespace: api
  labels:
    app: staging-api
  annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik-external
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: Host(`staging-api.local.com`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: staging-api
          namespace: momo
          port: websecure
```

Comment: Show us your existing configuration and how you've tried to implement this configuration yourself. Traefik supports path-based routes ([docs](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#rule)), which seems to be what you're asking about.

Comment: @larsks I added my k3s config

Comment: Have you tried creating some path based rules? Your current configuration is using only a host-based rule, so it will match any request for `staging-api.local.com`.